# How to position a widget in middle of custom appbar Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, appbar

**EDIT:**
I want the icon to go in the circle that i have created, but i do now seem to succeed using Stack and Positioned:

```
actions: <Widget>[
        Stack(
          children: [
            Positioned(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/person.jpeg"),
                radius: 30,
                key: Key("1"),
              ),
              top: height,
              right: width/2,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(),
            )
          ],
```

where the width and height are

```
final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
```

**ORIGINAL POST:**
So i have been trying to make a custom appbar in flutter but the image i want to display in the middle of the page does not go where i need it to go.

Here is what i have so far, what i want is the image to be displayed in the center of the appbar(width/2 - radius) and with the full height (height - radius).

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyZGN.png

Thanks for your help!!

```
class ProfileAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String name;
  ProfileAppBar({this.name});
  Size get preferredSize => new Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return AppBar(
      shape: CustomShapeBorder(),
      leading: Row(
        children: [
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.home),
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/home");
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      title: Text(name ?? 'Username'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          child: CircleAvatar(
            backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/person.jpeg"),
            radius: 30,
            key: Key("1"),
          ),
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: width / 4 + 20),
        ),
        IconButton(
          iconSize: 30,
          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
          onPressed: () {
            final profileRoute = "/profile";
            bool isNewRouteSameAsCurrent = false;

            Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
              if (route.settings.name == profileRoute) {
                isNewRouteSameAsCurrent = true;
              }
              return true;
            });

            if (!isNewRouteSameAsCurrent) {
              Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, profileRoute);
            }
          },
        )
      ],
    );
  }
}

class CustomShapeBorder extends ContinuousRectangleBorder {
  @override
  Path getOuterPath(Rect rect, {TextDirection textDirection}) {
    Path path = Path();
    path.lineTo(0, rect.height);

    path.lineTo(rect.width, rect.height);
    path.lineTo(rect.width, 0);
    path.addOval(
      Rect.fromCircle(
        center: Offset(rect.width / 2, rect.height),
        radius: 40,
      ),
    );
    path.addOval(
      Rect.fromCircle(
        center: Offset(rect.width / 2, rect.height),
        radius: 40,
      ),
    );

    return path;[enter image description here][1]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can wrap entire `AppBar` with `Stack`

```
Stack(
        children: [
          AppBar(
            shape: CustomShapeBorder(),
            leading: Row(
              children: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/home");
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
            title: Text('Username'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(
                iconSize: 30,
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 20),
                onPressed: () {
                  final profileRoute = "/profile";
                  bool isNewRouteSameAsCurrent = false;
                  Navigator.popUntil(context, (route) {
                    if (route.settings.name == profileRoute) {
                      isNewRouteSameAsCurrent = true;
                    }
                    return true;
                  });

                  if (!isNewRouteSameAsCurrent) {
                    Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, profileRoute);
                  }
                },
              )
            ],
          ),
          Positioned(
            left: 0.0,
            right: 0.0,
            child: CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage("assets/images/person.jpeg"),
              radius: 30,
              key: Key("1"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

Answer (score 0):

One question about you problem. Do you want to simply center the image in the app bar or do you want to place it inside the circular custom shape you have created for the app bar?

If you simply want to center the image, I would move the current app bar title that has the users name to the leading widget and use a row to have those elements. Then I would put the circle avatar as the title of the app bar and set the centerTitle property to true to have it center the image in the middle.

If you want to place it the other way, you would have to use a stack and a positioned widget to adjust its position accordingly

Comment: I updated the post to include more information! It was my mistake, thank you for the quick response(in the updated post i explain why i cant think of a way for stack towork )